# imagemagick text as a hole on solid background

Tags: text, background, imagemagick, transparent

I am simply trying to create some text as image with IM.
I want the size of the image to be automatically adjusted to text length.
Also I need the background color to be a solid specified color (rgb 166,127,000 in this example), and text color to be "transparent". I mean text "as hole" on the background.

I could obtain it with the following command:

```
/opt/local/bin/convert \( -font /fonts/myFont.ttf -pointsize 25 -background none -fill 'rgb(166,127,000)' -gravity center +antialias label:'TEST'   \)  -channel a -separate +channel -negate -fill  -alpha set -channel RGBA -fill none -opaque black -fill 'rgb(166,127,000)' -opaque white  png:-
```

I am looking for a simpler way to do it. Also I am having problems with antialias and the text looks too bulky.

Thank You.